# Prevent SimpleXML from merging duplicate elements / tags?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, dom, simplexml

I have some non-standard XML from avendor with repeating elements.

SimpleXML and DOM are both merging my XML tags. How can I prevent this?

Is there a way to get them into an array without them merging?

#### My XML is something like this:

`<quiz>
    <settings>
      <user name="joe" email="blah@blah.com" />
    </settings>
    <questions>
         <multiplechoice id="1">
               <directions>What is 1+1?</directions>
               <answer correct="true" selected="false">2</answer>
               <answer correct="false" selected="false">4</answer>
               <answer correct="false" selected="true">1</answer>
               <answer correct="false" selected="false">0</answer>
         </multiplechoice>
         <truefalse id="2">
               <directions>0 > 1?</directions>
               <answer correct="true" selected="false">True</answer>
               <answer correct="false" selected="true">False</answer>
         </truefalse>
         <multiplechoice id="3">
               <directions>What is 2+1?</directions>
               <answer correct="true" selected="false">3</answer>
               <answer correct="false" selected="false">4</answer>
               <answer correct="false" selected="true">1</answer>
               <answer correct="false" selected="false">0</answer>
         </multiplechoice>
    </questions>
  </quiz>`

#### My PHP is like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata);
```

#### Whats happening?

No matter how I try it, SimpleXML is merging the `<multiplechoice>` elements into a single `array()` like this:

```
[questions] => Array
(
    [multiplechoice] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1}
                        )
                    [directions] => What is 1+1?
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2
                                    [1] => 4
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                        )
                   [directions] => What is 2+1?
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 3
                                    [1] => 4
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )
        )
    [truefalse] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2}
                        )

                    [directions] => 0 > 1?
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => True
                                    [1] => False
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

#### What I want:

The `<multiplechoice>` elements should be separate and in the initial order:

```
[questions] => Array
(
    [multiplechoice] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1}
                        )
                    [directions] => What is 1+1?
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2
                                    [1] => 4
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )
        )
    [truefalse] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2}
                        )

                    [directions] => 0 > 1?
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => True
                                    [1] => False
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
   [multiplechoice] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                        )
                   [directions] => What is 2+1?
                    [answers] => Array
                        (
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 3
                                    [1] => 4
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )
        )        
)
```

Comment: of course thats normal, you can't have duplicate keys, so it merges them inside of it

Comment: My question isn't whether its correct to do so, but rather if its possible to work around this. I am stuck with this non-standard XML from the vendor...

Comment: You can't have that in arrays/hashmaps. If you need the content in order, don't convert them to named arrays like that. If you need more functionality then _Simple_ XML provides, go for a `DOMDocument`. Note that this `XML` is not non-standard, it's quite valid, and order has always mattered in `XML`.

Comment: Do not use an array for this, use the XML object directly. Either SimpleXMLElement or the ones from DOMDocument. Order is preserved by both.

Comment: @hakre That was it thanks. @ Wrikken gave the full answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *what* you do with `DOM`, but it maintains order out-of-the-box here:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$questions = $dom->getElementsByTagName('questions')->item(0);
if($questions instanceof DOMElement){
        foreach($questions->childNodes as $child){
                if($child instanceof DOMElement){
                        var_dump($child->tagName, simplexml_import_dom($child));
                }
        }
}
```

---

Perfectly in order:

```
string(14) "multiplechoice"
class SimpleXMLElement#4 (3) {
  public $@attributes =>
  array(1) {
    'id' =>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  public $directions =>
  string(12) "What is 1+1?"
  public $answer =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "2"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "4"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "1"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
string(9) "truefalse"
class SimpleXMLElement#4 (3) {
  public $@attributes =>
  array(1) {
    'id' =>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  public $directions =>
  string(6) "0 > 1?"
  public $answer =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "True"
    [1] =>
    string(5) "False"
  }
}
string(14) "multiplechoice"
class SimpleXMLElement#4 (3) {
  public $@attributes =>
  array(1) {
    'id' =>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  public $directions =>
  string(12) "What is 2+1?"
  public $answer =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "3"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "4"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "1"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, you have achieved what other claimed impossible!

Answer (score 1):

as others incl. myself have outlined, it's not possible to put the tree structure into an array the way you ask for in your question.

XML is a tree structure, and multiple elements with the same name can exist on the same level. something that is not possible with arrays.

so it's really better to keep the **SimpleXMLElement**s as they are. They are much more comfortable to operate on the data than with handling an array.

However said said, it's still possible to create an array out of that data similar to what you ask for, but it needs special treatment of the structure therein. There is no general way to handle that.

For example: All child-elements from questions at their position, then keyed with their name:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//questions/*');

foreach ($result as &$rebuild) {
    $rebuild = [$rebuild->getName() => $rebuild];
}
unset($rebuild);
$result = ['questions' => $result];

$array  = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

The resulting array then is in this format which I think is not very practical to deal with:

```
Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [multiplechoice] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                )

                            [directions] => What is 1+1?
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2
                                    [1] => 4
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [truefalse] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                )

                            [directions] => 0 > 1?
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => True
                                    [1] => False
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [multiplechoice] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                )

                            [directions] => What is 2+1?
                            [answer] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 3
                                    [1] => 4
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```